# How is I/O implemented in C?

Tags: c

*The C Programming Language* says that I/O is not built into C and is instead accessed through `stdio.h`. But if `stdio.h` is written in C, how does `stdio.h` implement I/O?

I've looked at the source code and I don't understand it.

Comment: The same way any other library would implement some functionality... in code.

Comment: Operating system. Eventually, you must flush the buffer, which is implemented in C, by sending the buffered characters to the operating system for display or saving to a redirected file, and then clear the buffer so it can be reused for new content.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But how would one write code that would do that, if C does not have builtin support for I/O?

Comment: The library provides the support for I/O.

Comment: In some sense what you quoted is weird, because the C standard does provide [a function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) which you call to print text or to accept text input from the user. In other words, a C programming environment (the compiler, the libraries, the part of OS that provides a C-callable API, etc.) does provide I/O, and the claim that "... is not built into" is literally splitting hairs from their viewpoint.

Comment: `stdio.c` implements "standard I/O," which is what you quoted is referring to.  Standard I/O is very simple to use.  Under the hood, very intricate machine code (which is what C compiles to) accesses ports, moves bytes, and in general does all of the low-level things that make "standard I/O" possible.  That low-level stuff is much more difficult to write yourself, but it can be done, and the result would be a library file similar to `stdio.c`.

Comment: Read [Operating Systems : Three Easy Pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). Then install and use some Linux distribution. Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Study the source code of some [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) like [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) and of the [Linux kernel](http://kernel.org/), since they are all [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

Comment: Notice that `<stdio.h>` is not the source code of the *implementation* of *standard IO*, but mostly just of *declarations* of functions and types used in it. So you'll better say that *`stdio.h`* is *declaring* I/O functions, not implementing them. On my system standard I/O is implemented in some `libc.so` shared library and in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch we call that an API I tihnk :)

Comment: All that quote means is that the language does not have any special statements, expressions, or other syntactic constructs for doing I/O, as some other (older) languages do.  So, in C, I/O is done by calling other things, which is very much supported in C.  Ultimately, actual I/O is done by the operating system anyway, so applications make system calls to accomplish I/O, possibly thru other intermediate libraries, .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When K&R write that I/O isn't "built into" C, they mostly mean that I/O *statements* are not part of the language grammar.  By contrast, Fortran 77 has distinct I/O *statements*, such as the `PRINT` statement:

```
PRINT *, 'The value of X is', X
```

The C `stdio` library functions and the Fortran I/O statements all delegate I/O operations to the underlying system.  It's just that in C's case they bypass having to parse and translate high-level I/O statements into machine code.

Comment: The only correct answer so far.

Answer (score 7):

The standard library is typically going to call something in the OS to handle reading and writing the actual file. On POSIX (or similar) that would mostly be `read` and `write`, which can read or write files. On Windows, it'd typically be `ReadFile` and `WriteFile`. Windows also supplies `ReadFileEx` and `WriteFileEx`, but they're mostly for doing asynchronous I/O, which the standard library doesn't (yet) support.

From there, execution will typically descend through (at least) a file system driver, a file system cache, and a device driver for the disk, SSD, or whatever sort of device is being used to store the file in question. Alternatively, the data could go through a sockets layer, and from there to a device driver for a network interface.

The precise details of transferring the data to the hardware varies (pretty widely), but in a typical case on modern hardware a great deal of it is actually handled by the target device itself. On the CPU you create a gather list for output or a scatter list for input. This is basically just a small chunk of the CPU's page tables, to tell target device what physical pages it needs to read (for output) or write (for input).

This is necessary because (at least on most typical OSes) you're allocating memory with virtual addresses--what your program sees as "contiguous" memory may be scattered around rather randomly in physical memory. Most hardware<sup>1</sup> doesn't know about that address translation, however, so it needs to be supplied with the physical addresses of the individual pages of memory where you data resides.

Also note that in a typical case (e.g., a typical file on disk), what you issue as a single call to `fwrite` might get translated into a number of actual I/O operations with the disk drive. If you write part of a sector, your write might translate to reading an entire sector into a buffer, overwriting part of that buffer, then writing the modified buffer out to the disk.

---

<sup>1. The major exceptions are some video adapters, and RDMA network adapters. These have memory in which the device driver maintains a shadow copy of the CPU's address translation tables, which the hardware then uses to translate the addresses, thus reducing the load on the CPU.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I/O operations are not part of the C language in the sense that the names and signatures of the I/O functions are not magically know in your program. Instead you need a `#include <stdio.h>` to tell the compiler about the names and signatures of the I/O functions.

The implementation of those functions is in the standard library, which may or may not be written in C, although for the I/O functions it is likely that they are written in C and delegate some work to functions provided by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Device drivers are very hardware dependent. Some hardware uses memory mapped I/O (that is you read/write to dedicated memory addresses to control I/O devices). Others have special purpose registers and opcodes. While the first could be handled with C, it still varies from machine to machine (timing, addresses). The second simply needs assembler to talk to the hardware properly. Still you can use C in this case, but it contains a lot of direct assembler code. So actually

> accessed through `stdio.h`

means that behind this header you will find very low level stuff.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite some answer but none talk about File Descriptor / Handle, which is the core about how IO are managed by the OS.

When you open a file, or a socket, or anything else you use for IO, you get a pointer to a [FIle Descriptor/FD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) (linux) or an Handle in Windows which is 
the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964907/is-handle-similar-to-file-descriptor-in-linux).

Basically the OS, whether it's Linux or Windows, has a table of those FD/Handle and when you call an IO on them, you're not writing in the file, you're asking to the OS that *you want to perform the operation X on the handle Y*. Those things are so low-level (see @JerryCoffin answer) that you don't do that yourself, instead you use stdio library which wrap this for you. The rest it's the OS, with all the drivers and hardware that will handle the stuff for you.

This is thanks to that abstraction (FD/Handles+OS+drivers) that you can use File operations quite transparently whatever the Disk is Formatted in FAT/NTFS/EXT4. Though there are some limits (ie : FAT 32  : no more than 4G file).